# see through/invisible white text shadow

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a an html element in the DOM;

```
<h5 class="white-shadow"> Basic </h5>
```

It has the following css rule attached;

```
.white-shadow{
    text-shadow: -1px 0px 5px #ffffff; 
}
```

The `h5` is within a list element that has a gray background. The idea is to add the white text shadow for better readability. The odd thing is that I see no results.

This is what I see in the browser;

[image: html]

This is what devtools shows me;

[image: devtools]

But if I change the background color from white to red I am able to see the change.

This is what I see in the browser;

[image]

This is what devtools shows me;

[image]

I haven't touched the alpha parameter of the text shadow rule. For some reason the red text shadow color is visible while the white text color is not.

I am using bootstrap3, although I don't expect that it is blocking white text shadows anywhere.

Why can't I see the white shadow around the text? How could I fix it?

Comment: It is working: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZkHg/

Comment: Works - http://jsfiddle.net/Y45Fk/1/ , it's just that the hex difference is not much, cuz #eee, and #fff are not too dark and light shades

Comment: Agreed: http://jsfiddle.net/t4cQy/ This is either the bg and text-shadow color being too close or a CSS specificity / override issue.

Comment: Ah yes. I now see. The background color is #eeeeee, which is too similar to  #ffffff to be spotted by the blind eye, even when zoomed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shadow is there in the DOM but because of your `background-color`, it is not much noticeable 
 [**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/btAK9/)

My suggestion, either change `shadow color` or `background-color`

[**here is what you want**](http://jsfiddle.net/btAK9/2/)

use

```css
.white-shadow{
    text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #fff, -2px 0 0 #fff, 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 #fff, 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

`text-shadow` value quoted from thread : [Text border using css (border around text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426875/text-border-using-css-border-around-text)

Comment: ah yes. by repeating the css rule they will overlap and cause more of an effect. nice solution.