# Set a text opacity to 0 but keep the border

Tags: html, css

I want to create a text where the *body* of each letter is to be completely transparent (or set a certain opacity) but the shape of it is to be just the border.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426875/text-border-using-css-border-around-text) post I saw a way to create a border around text. However, it is created based on the *actual state* of the text, so if I change its opacity, the border responds to that.

How could I create this border I am looking for?

Comment: So you're basically looking for CSS that only shows the _outline_ of the text?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/B3zCq/

Comment: @S.B. not exactly, you are setting the color to white, while it should be transparent, the *content* of the letter should be the image or whatever is in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to set **color** of the text to **rgba(255,255,255,0)**, the **-webkit-text-stroke-width** to **1px** and the **-webkit-text-stroke-color** to **#000** or any other color you would like to use

So it will be like this :

```
h1 {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
}
```

Maybe this link will help you, it has more details about **RGBA** colors

[A brief introduction to Opacity and RGBA](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/)

Hope this will help you ...

Comment: I used `text-shadow` instead, but the key to the matter was to set the color to `rgba(255,255,255,0)`. I was using just `opacity`.

Comment: If you used `text-shadow` in combination with a transparent font color, the shadow would always be visible behind the "transparent color", so this doesn't exactly work as you described it.

Comment: @S.B. that is what I exactly want. The shadow acts as a border.

Comment: No, that shadow will also act as a fill-in, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/B3zCq/1/. Either your question is misleading or you can't use text-shadow then.