# CSS Text Shadow according to text

Tags: html, shadow, css

I have taken 2 different titles/images merged as single as per image below.

[image]

I want to create shadow/border as per text design on top and bottom.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426875/text-border-using-css-border-around-text

Answer (score 0):

CSS text-shadow cannot do this as it isn't able to be expanded larger than the size of the original text (only blurred).

The closest you could get to this using only CSS would be with text-stroke which is currently in Blink and WebKit. Unfortunately it overlaps the text so the original text wouldn't be readable if you expanded the stroke to the size you need.

There is however a solution if you're willing to use a bit of jQuery. It's quite length so I will refer you to the site where it was first introduced http://www.petercarrero.com/examples/stroke/

Hope that helps.