# Overlay 2 texts HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Okay so i basically want 2 titles to overlap eachother so that the white one looks like a border around the black one, however i cannot seem to figure it out, the light grey box is the div.

[image: Link to screenshot]

Files:

```css
body {
 background-image: url("indexbg.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
h1.titleTATF {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "coalition";
 font-size: 100px;
 color: black;
}

h1.shadowTATF {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "coalition";
 font-size: 104px;
 color: white;
}

div.wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.25);
 width: 90%;
 text-align: center;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: coalition;
 src: url(Coalition.tff);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="icon" href="tabicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <h1 class="shadowTATF">TATF</h1>
   <h1 class="titleTATF">TATF</h1>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use text-shadow?

Comment: Well the text shadow only adds the shadow to one side of a text, it isn't an outline of the text

Comment: I'll make an example for you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426875/text-border-using-css-border-around-text

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with text-shadow instead of overlapping 2 titles.

```css
.titleTATF {
  text-align: center;
 font-family: "coalition";
 font-size: 104px;
 color: white;
  text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="titleTATF">TATF</h1>
</div>
```