# Style text track using videojs

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

Is there a way to style videojs captions?

The `nativeTextTracks` is set to false and I can see that the plugin is rendering his own caption.
A new div created for each row of text and the style of that div is inline.
I tried to send settings to the player init but videojs documentation is a bit lacking in this respect.

```
var player = videojs('my_video', {
    'html5': {
        nativeTextTracks: false
    },
    textTracks: {
        ??? maybe something here ???
    },
    'fluid': true,
    controlBar: {
        children: {
            'playToggle':{},
            'currentTimeDisplay':{},
            'timeDivider':{},
            'durationDisplay':{},
            'progressControl':{},
            'fullscreenToggle':{},
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an undocumented feature. You can learn more by reading the [`TextTrackSettings` source code](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/src/js/tracks/text-track-settings.js#L76). Basically, you need to call `setValues` on the settings of your player, and then to apply the settings with `updateDisplay`:

```
let player = videojs('my_video');
player.ready(function(){
    var settings = this.textTrackSettings;
    settings.setValues({
        "backgroundColor": "#000",
        "backgroundOpacity": "0",
        "edgeStyle": "uniform",
    });
    settings.updateDisplay();
});
```

Comment: Here's a link to the doc: https://docs.videojs.com/texttracksettings#setValues, and if you want to get them you can use: https://docs.videojs.com/texttracksettings#getValues

Comment: Where is the player's textTrackSettings-object available?

Answer (score 0):

I've done with the [css selector >](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

This will override the default black background and [add a black border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426875/text-border-using-css-border-around-text) around the letters:

```css
.vjs-text-track-cue > div {
    background: transparent!important;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 black, -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 0 -2px black,
                 1px 1px black, -1px -1px black, 1px -1px black, -1px 1px black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced the same issue when I was needed to add padding. I have investigated a lot and found that cue can only work on following properties:

1. **color**
2. **opacity**
3. **visibility**
4. **text-decoration**
5. **text-shadow**
6. **background**
7. **outline**
8. **font**
9. **line-height**
10. **white-space**

**For example** :

```
Ex : 1
video::cue {
   color:#ccc;
}

Ex : 2
video::cue {
   outline:5px solid gray;
}
```

So we just need to apply css for video::cue to play with Caption Track Text in any Video Player